# Positive mass but negative/positive/neutral charge

Tags: energy, particle-physics, mass, charge, unitarity

I have heard that the mass of a particle can't be negative because the hamiltonian should be bounded from below. What is the formal argument regarding this and why the same argument doesn't follow when we are talking about charges?

Answer (score 1):

The mass of a particle cannot be negative because we know of no 2 uncharged particles that repel each other.  Hence Newtons law is always attractive. There are negatively charged particle so Coulomb's force could be attractive or repulsive.

Comment: From what i know is that as gravitation field is described as 2 rank tensor field masses cannot repel each other and as Electromagnetic field is described by vector field, charges can attract or repel each other.

Comment: @RandomXYZ  your statement puts the cart infront of the horse. It is because one has observed two types of charges but one type of mass that the appropriate theories were **chosen** . It is not the theories that generated the data.

Comment: Yes @annav I agree with you that my remarks were not right but these have nothing to do with my question which asks how the argument of bounded Hamiltonians from below allow us to accept only positive mass?

Comment: Your question is this " mass of a particle can't be negative *because* the hamiltonian should be bounded from below." , italics mine. this is cart before the horse. The halmitonians were **chosen** to fit the observations.

Comment: Yes again I agree with your point @annav and I have stressed it enough that I want the formal arguments which are followed to achieve the experimentally verified result that mass is always positive i.e. in other words how making the hamiltonians bounded from below allow us to achieve our dearest experimental result of mass being positive.

Comment: @RandomXYZ  this is a question for a mathematics forum, not a physics one, what makes one hamiltonian model to have only positive masses, and another, the coulomb one to  have postivie and negative charges. I suspect it is two different mathematical problems, as charge is quantized in units of 1/3 whereas mass is the length of the four vectors entering the problem.